# PLS-00103 caused by PL SQL Declare keyword

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am learning PL SQL and running the below code --

```
 create or replace PROCEDURE PROCEDURE1 AS 

DECLARE
  c VARCHAR2(60 CHAR);
BEGIN
  c := 'abc  ';
END;



END PROCEDURE1;
```

However, this is giving error like below ==

Error(3,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of the following: begin function pragma procedure subtype type current cursor delete exists prior external language

Any help why this error is coming and how this can be removed?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? (PL/SQL is for Oracle only.)

Comment: I am using PL/SQL, removed the mysql tag now

Comment: You can even add <oracle>, to get better attention.

Comment: added oracle tag

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/CREATE-PROCEDURE-statement.html#GUID-5F84DB47-B5BE-4292-848F-756BF365EC54

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not "paste a working anonymous block between "create" and "end". In a procedure the `DECLARE` and `END` statement are not needed. The `CREATE PROCEDURE` will service as `DECLARE` and the `END [PROCEDURE_NAME];` serves as end. Google "Oracle create procedure syntax" for more info.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PROCEDURE1 AS 
  c VARCHAR2(60 CHAR);
BEGIN
  c := 'abc  ';
END PROCEDURE1;
```